# How to validate a complete syntax in text file using python?

Tags: python, validation

I have a .txt file having change log information,there will be some details as:

```
* Mon Jan 31 2012 raj sharma<john.doe@gmail.com> - 1.4.5.6
  - This is the change
```

Now this change log will be having one specific standard as:

```
 -* day month date year name <email address inside brackets> - version numbr
```

Now i have to construct a method inside python which shall validate the syntax of the change log as entered by user against the standard syntax as above. So, how shall i make that function which could validate the syntax of changelog.txt?

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest using regex to match the line and extract the matching group, and verify content of the matched group one by one. For example

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

line = '* Monday Jan 31 2012 Ram Sharma <Ram.Sharma @gmail.com> - 1.4.5.6'

m = re.compile(r"^\* ([A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+) (.*) <(.*@.*)> - ([0-9.]+)$")
result = m.search(line)
if result:
        print result.lastindex
        for i in range(result.lastindex+1):
                print i, result.group(i)
```

Using this piece of code, you can extract the date, name, email, and release version like this:

```
4
0 * Monday Jan 31 2012 Ram Sharma <Ram.Sharma @gmail.com> - 1.4.5.6
1 Monday Jan 31 2012
2 Ram Sharma
3 Ram.Sharma @gmail.com
4 1.4.5.6
```

You can verify the date in result.group(1), the email address in result.group(3), and the release version in result.group(4). Hope this direction helps.